# Applying semantic rules to bison

Tags: c, bison, lex

I am having trouble with this Bison program. It has to receive a string of 1s and 0s with a period like "101.101" by multiplying them by 2^n. For example:

```
 "101.101" = (1*2^2)+(0*2^1)+(1*2^0)+(1*2^-1)+(0*2^-2)+(1*2^-3)=5.625
```

The point tells when the pow is positive or negative. I have the following semantic actions:

```
S→ L.R 
 S→ L  
 L → L1 B   
 L → B  
 R → R1 B  
 R → B   
 B→ 0  
 B → 1  
 Sematic Rules  
 L.pos=0;R.pos=-1;S.val=L.val+R.val  
 L.pos=0;S.val=L.val;  
 L1.pos = L.pos + 1; B.pos = L.pos; L.val = L1.val + B.val;  
 B.pos = L.pos; L.val = B.val;  
 R1.pos = R.pos - 1; B.pos = R.pos; L.val = L1.val + B.val;
 B.pos = R.pos; L.val = B.val;  
 B.val=0;  
 B.val = 1*2B.pos;
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to add the variables like .val and .pos to the Bison file and then implement the C code programming.

Bison

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void yyerror (char *string);
int down =0;

%}
%token r1
%token l1
%token DOT
%token ZERO
%token ONE

%%

s: l DOT r
 | l
 ;

l: l1 b
 | b
 ;

r: r1 b
 |b
 ;

b: ONE
 | ZERO
 | error
 ;

%%
#include "lex.yy.c"

void yyerror (char *string){
  printf ("%s",string);
}

main (){
    yyparse();
}
```

Lex File

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
BINARY [0-1] 
%%
"1" {return ONE;}
"0" {return ZERO;}
"." {return DOT;}
%%
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this, it's not exactly what you want but it shows how to give rules in yacc a type and how to put C code into the rules.

```
The C code is in braces { } 
$$ means "this rule"
$1 means "argument 1"
$2 means "argument 2"

So the rule
    r : r b     
and the code 
   { $$ = $1 << 1 | $2; } 
means 
   r = r << 1 | b
```

The yacc file is:

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void yyerror (char *string);
int down =0;

%}

%union { // %union is needed to tell yacc about the types your rules will return
    unsigned val; // rules with type "val" will return unsigned
};


%token DOT
%token ZERO
%token ONE

%type <val> l r b; // rules l, r, and b are of type val

%%

s : l DOT r { printf("l.r = 0x%x.0x%x\n", $1, $3); }
  | l       { printf("l = 0x%x\n", $1); }
  ;

l : l b     { $$ = $1 << 1 | $2; } // l = l << 1 | b
  | b       { $$ = $1; } // l = b
  ;

r : r b     { $$ = $1 << 1 | $2; } // r = r << 1 | b
  | b       { $$ = $1; } // r = b
  ;

b : ONE     { $$ = 1; } // b = 0
  | ZERO            { $$ = 0; } // b = 1
  // | error
  ;

%%
//#include "lex.yy.c"

void yyerror (char *string){
  printf ("%s",string);
}

int yywrap() { return 1; }

int main (){
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

lex file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
"1" {return ONE;}
"0" {return ZERO;}
"." {return DOT;}
%%
```

Note that the lex file includes "y.tab.h". This is created by the command

```
yacc -d file.y
```

Running is like this, where the program is named "x":

```
[Charlies-MacBook-Pro:~] crb% cat i
011.110
[Charlies-MacBook-Pro:~] crb% x < i
l.r = 0x3.0x6
```

You can change the code do your arithmetic however you want. Or you
can make a function call in the "s" rule and pour over the bits l and r
in that.

Comment: Beat me to it :) I was just doing one, but with a value type of `struct {int val; int pos;};` which models the OP a bit better. But carry on...

Comment: Either way, sounds like yours is better. I was lazy. I'm not very good at explaining stuff. You could eval l and r as doubles on the fly. Maybe from both answers the OP will be able to figure it out.